# Determine properties of items in PVP after scaling

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I recently tried my LVL20 free to play account again and noticed that when I was in PVP, I actually became LVL29. The item levels of my gear were also scaled to 34 or 35.

Now I am stuck with the following problem: because items change upon entering PVP, I don't know how to compare them anymore. For Items that I already have I could just try them all, but I just have no idea what to hunt for now.

So, my question is:

#### Given an item, how can I determine in advance how good it will be for PVP?

---

I have already looked for a guide or database, but didn't find one that took this mechanism into account. I have also not found any formula to use.

Comment: If this is hard to answer in general, a specific way to help me figure out which gear to get as F2P would also be ok.

Comment: This site has tips and gear lists for all classes: http://www.epicf2p.com/wow-pvp-twink-guide

Comment: I am currently looking at creating a site, where you can look this up. All I need is the formula, then I will be able to do this.